# Use Protractor-perf with perfjankie

Tags: protractor, couchdb

I was wondering if anyone had managed to get this set up and working yet?  There are a few old posts about it but no solutions.  The creator has hinted that it should be possible by saving the protractor-perf stats to a couchDB database and then using the perfJankie dashboard to get them out again.  Which seems do-able, but this is where I have hit a snag:

- I have set up my couchDB database
- I have setup the perfjankie dashboard to run on a server and poll the couchDB database
- I have    got protractor saving the protractor-perf metrics to the
  couchDB

  BUT,

  I can't quite figure out how to get the metrics into the database in the correct format to get them out again?

PerfJankie is polling the database on http://127.0.0.1:5984/mydb/_design/pagelist/_view/pages?group=true
(I know there are more views but this is a start).

and I have that _design in my database, but I'm not sure how to use it on data that I'm uploading, or quite where to upload to.

If anyone can offer any suggestions or advice that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the example result file: https://github.com/axemclion/perfjankie/blob/master/test/res/sample-perf-results.json

If protractor-perf gives a similar results, then you should be able to see the results on the page.